# How to place two div's inside bootsrap columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am tying to place two divs inside a column. However, when I add margins or float property it doesn't help.

```
<div class="col-xs-1">
            <div class="main-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" /></div>
            <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        </div>

.arrow-down {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 7px solid transparent;
border-right: 7px solid transparent;
border-top: 7px solid black;
float: right;
margin-top:5px;}

.main-checkbox {
width:13px;
margin-left:10px;}
```

I need to get a checkbox and a little triangle next to it.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see if it's work. Just add **pull-left** which is already existed in bootstrap css. It acts like **float:left**. So you don't need to write any stylesheet anymore.

```
<div class="col-xs-1">
 <div class="main-checkbox pull-left">
 <input type="checkbox" /></div>
 <div class="arrow-down pull-left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `display:inline-block;` to it like:

```
.arrow-down {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 7px solid transparent;
   border-right: 7px solid transparent;
   border-top: 7px solid black;
  margin-top:5px;
   display: inline-block;
}
.main-checkbox {
   width:13px;
   margin-left:10px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

SEE **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n2bJk/)**